# Tensorflow, try and except doesn't handle exception

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow and I've been stuck at an annoying problem here.

I'm making a program that loads image "raw data" taken with `tf.WholeFileReader.read(image_name_queue)` from a tfrecord file and then decodes it with `tf.image.decode_jpeg(raw_data, channels=3)` and then passes it through a function that vectorizes it.

**main code**

```
logging.info('setting up folder')
create_image_data_folder()
save_configs()

logging.info('creating graph')
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([
                                             configs.TFRECORD_IMAGES_PATH],
                                             num_epochs=1)

image_tensor, name_tensor = read_and_decode(filename_queue)
image_batch_tensor, name_batch_tensor = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
                                        [image_tensor, name_tensor],
                                        configs.BATCH_SIZE,
                                        1000 + 3 * configs.BATCH_SIZE,
                                        min_after_dequeue=1000)
image_embedding_batch_tensor = configs.IMAGE_EMBEDDING_FUNCTION(image_batch_tensor)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
init_local = tf.initialize_local_variables()
logging.info('starting session')
with tf.Session().as_default() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(init_local)
    tf.train.start_queue_runners()

    logging.info('vectorizing')
    data_points = []
    for _ in tqdm(xrange(get_n_batches())):
        name_batch = sess.run(name_batch_tensor)
        image_embedding_batch = sess.run(image_embedding_batch_tensor)
        for vector, name in zip(list(image_embedding_batch), name_batch):
            data_points.append((vector, name))

logging.info('saving')
save_pkl_file(data_points, 'vectors.pkl')
```

**read_and_decode** function

```
def read_and_decode(tfrecord_file_queue):
    logging.debug('reading image and decodes it from queue')
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(tfrecord_file_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example,
        features={
            'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'name': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        }
    )
    image = process_image_data(features['image'])

    return image, features['name']
```

The code is working, but eventually it comes across a bad, non-jpeg file and an error this is raised and the **program stops running**.

**error**

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Invalid JPEG data, size 556663
```

I want to skip these "errors". I tried to surround the code with `try` and `except`.

**new code**

```
for _ in tqdm(xrange(get_n_batches())):
    try:
        name_batch = sess.run(name_batch_tensor)
        image_embedding_batch = sess.run(image_embedding_batch_tensor)
        for vector, name in zip(list(image_embedding_batch), name_batch):
            data_points.append((vector, name))
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning('error occured: {}'.format(e))
```

When I run the program again the same error occurs, the `try` and `except` **doesn't seem to handle the error**.

How can I handle these exceptions? Also, if you see that I've misunderstood the tensorflow "structure" please mention that.

Comment: Well, it should work. Could you describe what you mean by "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: Fixed, the try and except, didn't handle the error.

Comment: how did you fix it? I am having the same issue with tensorflow and try/except does not catch the exception :(

Comment: I didn't, I loaded the images and skipped the corrupt ones through SciPy, where I can handle exceptions.

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: any updates here?

Comment: any update here?

Comment: I was able to solve this by using `tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not applicable to your example, but I stumbled upon a different scenario in which TensorFlow didn't seem to catch the exception, despite doing

```
try:
    # Run code that throw tensorflow error
except:
    print('This won't catch the exception...')
```

The thing that made the problem so hard to solve was that TensorFlow debugging pointed to the wrong line; it showed me that the error lied in the graph construction, rather than graph execution.

**The concrete problem?**

I tried to restore a model from a .meta file:

```
try:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my_error_generating_model.meta') # tf throws err here
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
except:
    print('This won't run')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # This is where error is actually generated
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
    sess.run(...) # Propagating through graph generates a problem
```

The solution is, of course, to put your try-catch wrapper around the executing code instead!

Answer (score 1):

Well, to solve your issue use `tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors` available in v2.8.0

Use below transformation to produce a dataset that contains the same elements as the input, but silently drops any elements that caused an error. For example:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1., 2., 0., 4.])

# Computing `tf.debugging.check_numerics(1. / 0.)` will raise an
InvalidArgumentError.
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.debugging.check_numerics(1. / x, "error"))

# Using `ignore_errors()` will drop the element that causes an error.
dataset =
    dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors())  # ==> {1., 0.5, 0.2}
```

Refer documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/ignore_errors)

Comment: This helped to resolve my issue with tf.io.decode_jpeg exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with "except Exception" you will only catch exceptions that inherit from the generic class Exception, but not all exceptions.
If you want to catch your specific exception from tensorflow you can try:

```
try:
    # Your code
except tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError as e
    logging.warning('error occured: {}'.format(e))
```

If you want to catch any exception:

```
except: # Catch all exception
    logger.exception('error occured")
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me (same error) - even trying to catch any exception fails.

Comment: i don't follow: `tf.error.InvalidArgumentError` is a subclass of `Exception`, so (outside of `tf.function`), `except Exception` should catch `tf.error.InvalidArgumentError`

Comment: Joel you are right, if tf.error.InvalidArgumentError is a subclass of Exception, except Exception should catch it. But my answer was 4 years ago, and as far as I remember, this was not the case at that time in the version of tensorflow. I didn't check in the lastest, but probably they fixed that...