# TensorFlow Callbacks get the image that the model is currently using to train

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I got a dataset of 760000 png images.

Among them I believe there's only 1 rotted PNG image, that whenever TensorFlow steps on that image, it would return an error saying: `Unable to read the png image` or something, which would immediately stop the whole process.

Thus, how do I use the tensorflow callback, to retrieve the image that is currently used by the model, so I can operate on it and make it work?

If I choose to redo everything, it would take me at least 6 hours, and would even not necessarily solve the problem.

**A million thanks!!!**

**The Error**

```
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  Invalid PNG. Failed to initialize decoder.
     [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
  (1) Cancelled:  Function was cancelled before it was started
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_386342]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function
```

Code Area:

This is how I preprocessed the image (which shouldn't have any problems! The images are in DICOM formats, because I'm dealing with CT Images)

```
def window_img(dcm, width=None, level=None, norm=True):
    pixels = dcm.pixel_array * dcm.RescaleSlope + dcm.RescaleIntercept
    
    # Pad non-square images
    if pixels.shape[0] != pixels.shape[1]:
        (a,b) = pixels.shape
        if a > b:
            padding = ((0, 0), ((a-b) // 2, (a-b) // 2))
        else:
            padding = (((b-a) // 2, (b-a) // 2), (0, 0))
        pixels = np.pad(pixels, padding, mode='constant', constant_values=0)  
    if not width:
        width = dcm.WindowWidth
        if type(width) != pydicom.valuerep.DSfloat:
            width = width[0]
    if not level:
        level = dcm.WindowCenter
        if type(level) != pydicom.valuerep.DSfloat:
            level = level[0]
            

    lower = level - (width / 2)
    upper = level + (width / 2)
    img = np.clip(pixels, lower, upper)
    
    if norm:
        img = (img - lower) / (upper - lower)
    
    if (img.shape[0], img.shape[1]) != (512, 512):
        print(f'WARNING!! Special Shape:{img.shape}!! Padded!!')
        if img.shape[0] < 512:
            img = np.pad(img, ((512-img.shape[0])//2, (512-img.shape[1])//2), 'constant', constant_values=(0, 0))
        if img.shape[0] > 512:
            x = (img.shape[0]-512) // 2
            img = img[x:img.shape[0]-x, x:img.shape[0]-x]
    
    if len(img.shape) == 2 or img.shape[2] == 1:
        img = np.repeat(img.reshape(512, 512, 1), 3, axis=2)        
    return img
```

This is how I load the images

```py
training = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    '/data/images/train',
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='training',
    seed=1,
    class_names=['0', '1'],image_size=(512,512)
)
```

This is the model fit

```
model_s1_his_3 = model_s1.fit(
    training, validation_data=testing,
    batch_size=16, epochs=3,
    callbacks=[early_stopping, tensorboard_callback],
    class_weight={1:3.407, 0:0.586}
)
```

**EDIT 2**

I'm so sad that this question did not deserve attention! That's alright. So I've found the "inner ghost" by looking through the entire training set one by one. So when I use `plt.imread` to read that ghost, `matplotlib.pyplot` gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 121, in __init__
    self._open()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 691, in _open
    cid, pos, length = self.png.read()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 162, in read
    length = i32(s)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/_binary.py", line 75, in i32be
    return unpack_from(">I", c, o)[0]

error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 4 bytes


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-293-a6fc8216ee12>", line 1, in <module>
    plt.imread(f'/data/images/train/0/ID_3946c5d2a.png')

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2246, in imread
    return matplotlib.image.imread(fname, format)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 1496, in imread
    with img_open(fname) as image:

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 129, in __init__
    raise SyntaxError(v) from v

  File "<string>", line unknown
SyntaxError: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 4 bytes
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code you're using so that we know how you're reading the images?

Comment: @Berriel Sure! I'll make an edit right away

Comment: @Berriel By the way, the image reading process is done internally by TensorFlow.

Comment: Hi! Can you please  check the following link for catching the corrupt image  before you start the pre-processing .             
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56569342/detecting-corrupt-images-in-tensorflow/60049003#60049003